# Embedding Google map on my website

Tags: html, google-maps

I have created a google map on my google account. I am trying to embed it on my website. It shows a lot of unwanted information on top of the page like share, sign in, view in new window, name of map and so on. I want to remove this area as it is not looking good. Can anyone help me with this? Also i got iframe from the google maps but i want to get html code as every time my company needs to change the details of the map they would need my Login and password. If i had Html code than they would just edit it from the site itself. Here is the link to the map

http://www.karcher.com.au/aus/distributors_retailers/Karcher_Centers.htm

Comment: Since ist an Iframe and you cann't Access the code behind it you can't remove the TopBar. You could [Export](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=de) the data to an KML File and look for another map Service you can use wich dynamicly loads the KML File. Your Company would just neet to edit the KML File (XML Struktur)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I downloaded KML file and I will look for some map service to help me out. I tried Map Builder which was very good but they seem to place their company logo on my map. I have another thing though. If you click on any markers on my map, the content in the window does not have proper line breaks. I change in my map and look at the site the changes look different. Each statement is supposed to come on a new line. its all over the place

Comment: Found [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60159/how-to-create-line-break-on-google-maps-engine-lite) Thread about the line breaks. So `ALT + Enter` and `STRG + ENTER` should work for line break.

Comment: If you found a alternative to Google Maps please tell me. I would be interested to

Comment: Wow. That worked very well for me. Well I am still waiting for support team of Map Builder to help me out to purchase their map or remove their logo. Its very easy to build and looks better than google one to me.Also has good options to modify the map styles and markers. Its free to use or you can register for free too. Here's a link if you like to see how the same map looks on Map Builder.I still need to edit the content though, there may be typing errors. http://www.karchercenter.com.au/jmap.html

Comment: Yeah that map Looks better, did you do it  with http://www.mapbuilder.net/ ?

Comment: It's this one https://mapbuildr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarized:

Since its an iFrame and you cann't access the code behind it, you can't remove the TopBar.

1. Export the Map to an KML File -> [Google Help](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452)
2. Import to another Map Builder like https://mapbuildr.com

To add Line Breaks into the description Text use `ALT + ENTER` oder `STRG + ENTER`.